# Array list object help (static error)

Tags: object, arraylist, static

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class fester
{
    public static void main(String args[] )
    {

        ArrayList<BankAccount> ba = new ArrayList<BankAccount>();
        ba.add(new BankAccount("hi", 4));

    }

    class BankAccount
    {
        private String name;
        private double amount;
        public BankAccount(String name, Double amount)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.amount = amount;
        }

        public String getName()
        {
            return this.name;
        }

        public double getAmount()
        {
            return this.amount;
        }
    }
}
```

I dont get problem. I tried to almost copy this

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Collections-Data-Structure/Storeuserdefinedobjectsinarraylist.htm

and it works. I'm very lost, and I cant see the fundamental differences.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Are you able to post the error you're getting? Reading this might also help: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask or this http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

You constructed class `BankAccount` as nested inner class (which means that you need an object of the outer class in order to instantiate it).

Move it outside of fester and replace 4 with 4.0 it'll work:

```
class fester {
    public static void main(String args[]) {    
        ArrayList<BankAccount> ba = new ArrayList<BankAccount>();
        ba.add(new BankAccount("hi", 4.0));    
    }    
}

class BankAccount {
    private String name;
    private double amount;
    public BankAccount(String name, Double amount) {
        this.name = name;
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public double getAmount() {
        return this.amount;
    }
}
```

Comment: 
You should follow Java naming convention and rename `fester` to `Fester` (with a capital letter).

Comment: Thanks man, I cant believe I didnt catch that. I feel foolish now.